# iOS 13 - Can we use xib as a launch screen over launch storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib, ios13

As Apple announced during WWDC with their new requirement that by April 2020, all apps should adopt Launch Storyboards because they will be deprecating launch images.

My question is, can we use a launch screen xib file over a launch storyboard file? Or is there another reason why they recommend specifically using a launch storyboard because storyboards are usually faster and allocate less memory?

From Apple documentation:

> In iOS 13 and later, always provide a launch storyboard for your app. > Don’t use static launch images.

Comment: What would be the benefit of using a XIB?  A launch storyboard only contains one scene and no code, so it is effectively a single XIB file wrapped in a storyboard.

Comment: Opted into using a xib because of the need to show it in a view controller that contains some logic when launching the app. Just wondering if this new requirement excludes launch xibs!

Comment: As far as I know you can still use a XIB file, you just can't use images.  I think Apple is just using the word storyboard for simplicity and because in general they suggest storyboards over xib files.

Comment: @Paulw11 you were correct! With the release of XCode 11 beta 4, they included this in their release notes:

"Your app might fail to build if it contains a launch image. The failure message resembles the following: “The launch image set named <image set name> did not have any applicable content.” Launch images are deprecated and should be removed; use a launch storyboard or .xib file instead. (50210495)"

Answer (score 5):

Found my answer! With the release of XCode 11 beta 4 yesterday, Apple included the following in their release notes:

> Your app might fail to build if it contains a launch image. The
>   failure message resembles the following: “The launch image set named
>    did not have any applicable content.” Launch images
>   are deprecated and should be removed; use a launch storyboard or .xib
>   file instead. (50210495)

Comment: When I select "Use as Launch Screen" in IB on my .xib, it still doesn't appear as an option in the drop down for the app's launch screen. If I type the xib's name manually (with or without the extension) I just get a blank screen. What am I missing?